# How do I intentionally put a process into a uninterruptible state in windows?

Tags: windows, debugging

I need to put a process into a uninterruptible state where it shall remain for a long period of time.

From my understanding, I need to find system call that is not allowed to be interrupted, then stall it so it indefinitely remains in a unkillable state.

What would be a sure way to do this?

Comment: Hm. Why? An unkillable program sounds kind of anti-social, it could tie up necessary resources indefinitely, and reduce the reliability of the O/S.

Comment: This is for debugging purposes.

Comment: There's no reliable way to do that from user-mode code.  You'll have to write a device driver.  (I'm not sure whether that will work either.)